# Unity Keyboard Movement Easing?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, camera, controls

I am trying to replicate the editor's camera for runtime use, and all is working as expected, but I am trying to Ease the movement and can't get it working right. Here is my code for the movement. It works correctly but isn't Eased out like I want.

```
             Vector3 move = Vector3.zero;

             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
                 move += Vector3.forward * currentSpeed;
             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
                 move -= Vector3.forward * currentSpeed;
             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
                 move += Vector3.right * currentSpeed;
             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
                 move -= Vector3.right * currentSpeed;
             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
                 move += Vector3.up * currentSpeed;
             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
                 move -= Vector3.up * currentSpeed;

             transform.Translate(move);
```

I have tried a destination Vector3, setting that to `move`, then lerping the position to `destination`.  This does Ease it as expected, but then the directions are all broken.  Left moves forward, right moves back, and so on.

I have tried moving to fixedUpdate but still no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation, easing/smoothing can be achieved by doing the following in an update loop:

```
float x, y, z;
x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
y = 0;
transform.Translate(x,y,z);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use CharacterController. It is component from Unity. It is easy to use and smooth.

```
public CharacterController controler;

public void Start(){
controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();}

public void Move(){
controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);}
```

On youtube you can find tutorials from CharacterController.

Comment: I did look into it, but because it's not a character per se and is literally just a camera that I am trying to move, I don't think it would be appropriate.  I'm really just looking for a way to smooth out the code I already have because it works perfectly right now (except smoothing)

Comment: Then try this. It is simple 2d movement, but you can use it on camera too.         
`public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    private float moveSpeed = 0.5f;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0 || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") != 0) {
            transform.position += moveSpeed * new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        }`

Comment: I appreciate the contribution but based on the existing code I provided, I'm not sure how it's applicable.  Additionally, there doesn't seem to be any smoothing applied, which is what I need help with.  In any case, thank you for your time!

Comment: I realize that the correct word is "Easing", not smoothing.  I apologize for any confusion.